# Finding duplicates in table with different sql queries yields different results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was expecting both queries to give the same outcome. Why is this not the case?

```
select count(*) as c,number from numbers group by number having count(*) > 1;

select * from numbers as a INNER JOIN numbers  as b 
                                    on a.number = b.number  and a.id < b.id;
```

First query return 1661 results where as the second 1911.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the first query will *always* return one row per number.
The second may return more rows with the same number (if you have triplicates etc)

try the below to see the difference

```
SELECT a.number, count(*) FROM
(select * from numbers as a INNER JOIN numbers  as b 
   on a.number = b.number  and a.id < b.id) c
GROUP BY a.number
-- having count(*) > 1
-- ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Never again. Never again will I run sql queries without sleep! you are absolutely right. Some numbers have 3 occurrences!

Answer (score 0):

The first query is correct, showing you one row for each number.

But the second query shows you all combinations of equal numbers (see the fiddle). If you have more than two records with the same number, the number of records when you JOIN will increase.

If you have:

```
ID     NUMBER
1        1
2        1
3        1
4        2
5        3
```

Joining these two tables will result in three times the number 1 being displayed.

Here you can see a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/86dd3/6) and how your query works.